# disabled scrollbar despite having overflow auto

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a container which has `overflow-y: auto`, which works pretty well, it shows scroll when needed and hides when not needed. But at certain content height, it gets to the point where the scroll bar is in the disabled state and it happens sporadically.

I'm trying to figure out if it's a bug in the browser or something that I can control? Is it a known issue? See the screenshot below

[image]

Code sample

```
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; /* inherits from body */
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
}

.grandChild {
  /* this can grow as much as it can and .child handles the scroll */
}
```

Comment: Please add your code so it'll be easier to understand

Comment: Please create a code snippet so we can check what is the issue. thanks

Comment: Added a code snippet, I'll try to also add a Codepen link in the meanwhile

Comment: i have try to solve the problem of your scrollbar but i cant understand your problem properly please add code snippet to understand your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

for the scroll in the `.child` class you have to set the `height` or `max-height` to it otherwise it will never scroll your content.

```
.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 400px; /*for example.*/
}
```